# Is this correct C++0x code?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Tried this in GCC 4.6 and it compiles and links, but gives a "bus error" message on runtime on MacOS. VS2010 doesn't even compile it.

But the question is, should this actually work in standard C++0x?

```
#include <cstdio>
int (*main)()=[]()->int{printf("HEY!\n");return 0;};
```

Yes, what it's trying to do is to define "main" as a lambda function.

Comment: I love the way you're trying to use the latest, greatest, advanced features of C++11, but still insist on using `cstdio` and `printf` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: printf rocks!!! C++ failed at I/O streams :)

Comment: According to Stroustroup ... if C lets you shoot in the foot, C++ can blow all your leg off! This is what I call ... masochism! :-))

Comment: After having tried I/O streams in a project and finding them 10-20 times slower than the old C IO system, I've been sticking with the old one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a valid C++ program, because the symbol `main` is not defined to be a function, but rather a pointer to function. That's why you get segmentation fault -- the runtime is attempting to execute a pointer.

Comment: +1: (Removed my sloppy comment to the original question. That answer sort of better explains whats happening here.)

Comment: Then I guess it's actually a bug in GCC that it accepts this code as correct?

Comment: @hasvn, I'm not sure, but I think this is one of those instances in which no diagnostic is required by the standard. So gcc might be in the clear.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not correct.

Main is a special function and there are strict requirements for it (even more strict than a regular function), but you are also making some confusion between what is a function and what is a pointer to a function.

The logical problem is that there is a difference between a function and a variable holding a pointer to a function (what you want main to be).
A function has a fixed address in memory, so to call a function that address is simply called. A pointer to a function **points** to an address in memory, so to call the function you need first to read what the pointer is pointing to and then call that address.

A pointer to function has a different level of indirection from a function.

The syntax is the same... i.e. if `x` is a pointer to a function you can write `x(42)`, but still the generated machine code is different if `x` is instead a function (in the case of a pointer a value must be looked up and the call address is determined at run time, with a function the address is fixed - up to relocation - and is determined at link time).

Answer (score 0):

For portability among compilers and standard library implementations, printf() must be std::printf() when #including `<cstdio>`.  And the other stuff about the invalid main().

Comment: No, it's unspecified in the standard as to whether `cXXX` includes inject into the global namespace. It's _wise_ to use `std::` but "must" is probably an overkill.

Comment: OK, this was a half-joke anyway.  I'll edit the answer to note that it's required for portability.  (Those of us who write portable code for a living just start thinking this way...)

Answer (score 0):

Now, it should not even compile. The lambda expression yields a type (a functor). <strike>There is no implicit conversion from type to function pointer.</strike>

Depending on compiler, `main` function can have C++ or C linkage (it is implementation defined). Lambda expression returns C++ type with function call operator, thus C++ linkage.

Comment: There actually is an implicit conversion from a non-capturing lambda to a function pointer.

Comment: You both are right. Though, it implicitly converts to pointer to member function, not a free function. Vaguely remembering that might have confused me.